# ViewBinding with CardView Dialog Box not displaying width correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I'm having to migrate to ViewBinding in my Android app to comply with the latest target versions. I'm really struggling to get a dialog box created using CardView to display correctly.

The below is the script after I've made the modifications to use ViewBinding.

```
override fun addUserDialog() {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(Runnable {
        LoggerUtils.logMessage("PMN Calling MFA User Dialog")
        var dialog = Dialog(this)
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setContentView(bindingMFA.root)
        dialog.setCancelable(false)
        bindingMFA.mBtnCancel.setOnClickListener {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        bindingMFA.mBtnConfirm.setOnClickListener {
            mMFACode = bindingMFA.mSMSMFA.text.toString()
            mLoginViewPresenter.confirmLogin(mMFACode)

            dialog.dismiss()
        }

        dialog.show()
        })

}
```

This appears within a file 'loginActivity.kt', where I set the binding within onCreate:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding
private lateinit var bindingMFA: DialogMfaBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
    bindingMFA = DialogMfaBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

If I change the line back to `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_mfa)` it shows the dialog box absolutely fine.

This is the dialog_mfa.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
app:cardElevation="8dp">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mLblInvitationHeader"
        style="@style/LabelTextMediumBold"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/background_blue"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/mfa_header"
        android:textColor="@color/text_white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mLblHeader"
        style="@style/LabelTextMedium"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/mfa_intro"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mLblInvitationHeader" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mSMS_MFA"
        style="@style/LabelTextMedium"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mLblHeader" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mBtnCancel"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mBtnConfirm"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mSMS_MFA"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginEnd="4dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" style="@style/GeneralButtonGrey"
        android:text="@string/cancel"/>
    <Button
        android:text="@string/mfa_confirm"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mBtnConfirm"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mBtnCancel" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mSMS_MFA" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" style="@style/GeneralButton"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

If anyone is able to point out what I'm doing wrong, it would be very much appreciated!
[image: Screenshot showing dialog box with incorrect width]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
bindingMFA = DialogMfaBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
bindingMFA.window.setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Comment: Thanks - that almost worked. Only change is that bindingMFA didn't have a window attribute, but this worked `dialog.window?.setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`

Answer (score 0):

try adding android_layout_weight=1 to the textViews